# Gradle - exclude jars from WAR folder?

Tags: gradle, war

I need to exclude two .jar files from my webapp war output. The build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.30'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile project(':farms')
} 

war {
    exclude("**/bad1.jar")
    exclude("**/bad2.jar")
}
```

The project "farms" is what is including jars "bad1.jar" and "bad2.jar". I don't need them though in the output war. The exclude block I tried adding has no effect.

How can I stop those jars from being added?

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me in the past:

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude("**/bad1.jar")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/bad2.jar")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if exclude supports lazy but I would try this:

```
excludes {['**/bad1.jar', '**/bad2.jar']}
```

Something else you could do that I have done before is set the from for only the files you want.

```
/**
 * Get a FileTree using a String array of includePatterns and String array of excludePatterns
 * @return FileTree
 */
ext.getFiles = {List includePattern=null, List excludePattern=null ->
    FileTree fileTree = project.fileTree(dir: project.getRootDir())
    if (includePattern) {
        includePattern.each {
            fileTree.include(it)
        }
    }
    if (excludePattern) {
        excludePattern.each {
            fileTree.exclude(it)
        }
    }
    return fileTree
}
```

In your war task

```
from { getFiles(includePattern, excludePattern).files }
```

This will lazily get any files that match your includePattern's and exclude any files that do no match your excludePattern's. Additionally the .files will flatten the results. If that is not desired then remove it. Note this will search the entire project structure, to change that set: dir: project.getRootDir() to something different.